# <a> link to #something with page reload but no js

Tags: html, anchor, href

I have this anchor element:

```
<a href="mindex.html#clickableAnchor?showhide=1" id="clickableAnchor">
    <!-- some content -->
</a>
```

I need to pass all three elements in href attribute:

```
- URI mindex.html
- ID #clickableAnchor
- GET parameter showhide
```

URI is for reloading the page,
ID is for scrolling the page to anchor,
GET parameter is sent for php script which decides either to show or hide a menu placed just under the anchor.

Page is reloading, menu is showing/hiding but the window is not scrolling to #clickableAnchor.

I resolved the problem using jQuery (by toggling the menu) but I want this feature working ALSO without javascript.

What should I do?

Comment: Care to post a Fiddle of your markup? I'd like to see where you're anchoring to.

Answer (score 0):

The anchor part of a URL comes after the query string. See Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Url

Note that the browser won't scroll to the anchor if there is no scrollbar - if the page contents fit in the browser window, it can't scroll anywhere.

Comment: It should work - if you click the "share" link below my answer, and enter the URL you get into a browser, you'll get a URL that has a # anchor to this answer. You can add a random query string to the URL and it will still work.

Comment: According to your example with share link, I noticed that the anchor has a "name" attribute, not "id". I tried it (as well as both "name" and "id") but result is still the same. I have no idea what else can cause this problem.